# Cleverly locked myself out of Excel's VBA editor in my worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, editing

I'm working in Microsoft Excel 2010.

I was creating a worksheet that is supposed to be hard to screw with for the person other than me who uses it. To modify data in the sheet I utilized a userform that can not be ⊠'ed out nor moved around. This userform opens up at the startup of the workbook.

What I didn't remember is that, when the userform is open, I'm not allowed into the VBA editor to edit the code for the sheet and/or book. This is a problem since the code for the sheet isn't complete.

TL;DR: I'm an idiot and have created a immovable, impossible to ⊠ out userform with no 'Cancel' or 'End' button that opens on startup of the sheet and keeps me from opening Excel's VBA editor.

Help is desperately needed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd> to terminate the script. Then open the VBA editor as usual; e.g., with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>.

Comment: This has just saved my arse big time, cheers.

Answer (score 3):

Open a new instance of Excel. Go to options and then Trust Centre Settings. On the right hand side there is tab for Macro settings. Select it and disable all macros. Open your *locked* workbook and play around with the code.

Or

Open that workbook programmatically with events/macros disabled

```
Application.EnableEvents = False 
Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\workbook.xls" 
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also open the workbook that contains the code bypassing the Workbook_Open event by holding down the Shift key while selecting the file to open from excel. Then open VBA editor after and fix your code.